# Assigning SQL result to a Listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to build a listview which will have the format of

---

{PlayerAname} vs {PlayerBname}

{PlayerAScore} - {PlayerBScore}

---

So this is a more complex (atleast to me) listview as it will have 4 properties I would need to set in it...

I've looked for some tutorials or examples but haven't found what I was looking for. I need to know how to set the properties and how to build the layout of a single listview item

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a SimpleCursorAdapter. The [docs for ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) show how to bind an SQLite result set to a list view using a SimpleCursorAdapter, including how to direct each column into a particular field of the row. The example uses the stock `android.R.layout.two_line_list_item` row layout, but you can use your own to lay out the data in a row as you see fit.